# MyFaces @ViewScoped throws NotSerializableException even with server setting

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, myfaces

So I wish to use `ViewScoped` and when I set the state saving method to client the page will throw a `NotSerializableException` and the page will forward to the error page. When I switch to server state saving, the exception is still thrown but the page will load.

I read through many questions and answers and was under the impression that the combination of ViewScoped/server state saving will eliminate the need to have everything marked as Serializable. Anyone see this issue?

Richfaces 4.1/Myfaces 2.1.5

Comment: This is by the way specific to MyFaces. Mojarra doesn't show this behaviour. I don't follow MyFaces closely, so I have no idea why MyFaces guys explicitly require view scoped beans to be serializable. But what's wrong with making them serializable? You would in Mojarra run into the same issue anyway whenever the server restarts/redeploys while maintaining the same sessions so that session users can just continue their session/view-related activities.

Comment: Im wiring in alot of legacy services and EJB code and dont have the ability to mark everything down the chain as serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting this servlet context parameter will solve the issue:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This will prevent MyFaces from serializing the state before saving it in the session. Doing so is the default reason. I think it's for saving memory.

Comment: Thank you.  Adding that in the web.xml fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDI, you can use MyFaces CODI. It fixes this issue and you can use @ViewScoped beans as CDI bean.